# Neglect the positive values in negative interest rates modelling?

Tags: interest-rates, factor-models, negative, correlation-matrix

The magnitude of the negative interested rate should vary correlated with the increase in fixed assets prices and with cross-currency basis spreads.

Could their volatility / correlation coefficients, as historically fitted for all the previous non-negative observed interest rates be reliable and considered in backtesting the model?

Would it not be better to consider low data sampling analysis and fit them only since negative interest rates (not negative forward ones) have been observed on the market?